# Android Recyclerview type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have 2 types of models: Category and Subcategory. I want to display them in a recycler view with 2 different types of layouts. I know I can override the method `getItemViewType` but the problem is that the categories and subcategories can change (ie new items added or deleted) so I was wondering if it is possible to create such a recycler view. How can I determine whether an element at position `i` is a category or subcategory? I am using Realm with the library `https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview` but this question should apply to generic recycler views.

Comment: Add a variable to your model class to determine if the item is a category or subcategory. e.g. boolean isCategory; You can then check this flag before performing any action.

Comment: `How can I determine whether an element at position i is a category or subcategory? ` by position and indexing.

Answer (score 1):

For UI you can take type of element directly from your view holder implementation by calling [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getItemViewType()) method. It's allow to display particular layout.
At backend you need to call required `notifyItemXXX()` ([`notifyItemInserted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) for example) method for start execution of redraw mechanism - it's update your view at required positions.

**Take note**
You can't manually change data set if you using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` with default implementations of [`OrderedRealmCollection`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/OrderedRealmCollection.java) such as [`RealmResults`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmResults.java) and [`OrderedRealmCollectionImpl`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java). They are not support add/remove operations.
P.S. Current Realm version is 3.0.0.